# Какие знаки препинания здесь нужны?

Tags: пунктуация

Шамин (?) усталый литературный ремесленник (?) не решался бросить свою подёнщину (?) благодаря ей его семья не бедствовала (?) а решись он написать что-то серьёзное (?) и прощай сытая жизнь.

Какие знаки препинания здесь нужны?

Comment: Это не домашнее задание, behemothus. Конструкция ведь не слишком простая, а это главное. Мне сайт интересен только с точки зрения русского языка, и больше ни с какой точки зрения не интересен.)

Comment: БЛАГОДАРЮ ВСЕХ ЗА ОТВЕТЫ!

Comment: @behemothus Мне кажется "домашнее-задание" лучше ставить тегом. Все-таки ни о чем не говорящие заголовки - зло.

Comment: Да, конечно. Это я промахнулся. Вроде хотел написать комментарий. Другое дело, что исходный заголовок тоже ни о чем не говорит. Если есть тэг "пунктуация"....

Comment: @behemothus К сожалению не могу придумать толковых заголовков к таким вопросам (а подобных на сайте много).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно согласиться с предложенным вариантом, за исключением концовки.

"Шамин, усталый литературный ремесленник, не решался бросить свою подёнщину: благодаря ей его семья не бедствовала, а решись он написать что-то серьёзное - и прощай сытая жизнь".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Выражения "и прощай" оформляется различно: чаще всего перед союзом И ставится тире (или запятая),  реже встречается вариант с тире после союза И.

2) прощай сытая жизнь - в ф-ии сказуемого (не будет сытой жизни). В то же время обособление тоже возможно в связи с распространенностью обращения.

ПРИМЕРЫ

По болоту ползешь, как по минному полю: движение неосторожное ― и прощай, Мишка! (А. Н. Арбузов). Буря, одни испугались, ручки сложили, и все, их волной накрыло, и ― прощай, мама (Владимир Войнович).Нагрянут кредиторы, и прощай яхта, прощай вилла! (И. А. Ефремов). Будет педагогический совет, нам выдадут аттестаты зрелости, ― и прощай, гимназия, навсегда! (В. В. Вересаев).

Comment: Vera, а после "не бедствовала" точка с запятой не нужна?

Comment: Мне кажется, что точка с запятой здесь совсем не у места. После двоеточия идет общее разъяснение ситуации, поэтому предложения тесно связаны по смыслу.

Comment: Спасибо, V e r a !

Answer (score 1):

Шамин, усталый литературный ремесленник, не решался бросить свою подёнщину: благодаря ей его семья не бедствовала, а решись он написать что-то серьёзное и - прощай, сытая жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Шамин, усталый литературный ремесленник, не решался бросить свою подёнщину (благодаря ей его семья не бедствовала), а решись он написать что-то серьёзное - и прощай, сытая жизнь.
Конечно, двоеточие напрашивается после слова "поденщина", так как дальше объясняется, почему он не бросал подёнщину, но я чувствую и другой интонационный рисунок, согласно которому в скобки следует заключить слова, явялющиеся попутным замечанием, добавочной информацией к основному высказыванию